# Android APP + SQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I've already read, that there is not so simple, to connect directly from Android APP (Java code) to some SQL on the server (for example MySQL etc.) on the Internet.

I would be very happy, that some one could explain to me that question. Maybe simpler way, it would be create only some web page (on JSF, ASP.NET etc.)... although I would prefer native APP. There should be login in, and then, only after correctly login, instering (INSERT INTO...) data and downloading (SELECT...) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) and also [android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).